# Prevent deletion of Attachments from a SharePoint List Item

Tags: sharepoint, list, attachment

We have a **custom SharePoint list type**. Part of our list's functionality depends on the existence of a specific attachment for each list item. When the **user** accidentally or intentionally **deletes the attachment** (named DoNotDelete.fi!) of a list item our **functionality for that item is broken**. Therefore we would like to **prevent user from being able to delete that particular list item attachment** (but should be able to edit the list item otherwise).

Can this be achieved through the use of an **EventReceiver for this list item**? Given that the attachments are stored in the RootFolder of the list, maybe the EventReceiver needs to be attached not to the list item but elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, I have created such a construction once.

You have to implement the `ItemAttachmentDeleting` method of an `SPItemEventReceiver`. 
See all possible methods here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver_members.aspx